# How can I decode a JSON into array using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, facebook, cordova

Hi to all i have a problem with a JSON in Phonegap, i´m trying to do a login using facebook sdk and get some info for the profile but i get a JSON this is the JSON
using JSON.stringify():

```
 {
   "id":"facebookId",
   "first_name":"Joseluis",
   "last_name":"Fernandezmateo",
   "email":"myemail@hotmail.com",
   "gender":"male",
   "birthday":"09/30/1998"
 }
```

And what i want is to create an array that contains all data (first name, last name, id, and the other stuff) and returns the value of the data i mean
data['gender'] and this return his gender in this case male sorry if i could not explain me better but in my head all make sense, Thanks for the help

Comment: Firstly, that's an object. It's not stringified to JSON at all. Secondly you don't need to turn it in to an array. The object will already do what you require - in fact its the *only* way to do what you require: https://jsfiddle.net/ozb92ej0/

Comment: If getting single item in hand is the only conern, then use parseJSON. like,  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(responce); and you will be able to use obj.id, obj.first_name etc.

Comment: what do you want to do, and why would you use jquery for that? just use the json object in javascript. it´s not an array, it´s a json object. data.id, data.gender and so on (or data['id'])...those are javascript basics, you MUST learn how to handle json.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers i use luschn answer i just use data.email in order to get the email, sorry if look as a noob but I´m noob in web developing i´m learning web developing and in the meantime i develop and app anyways thanks for all answers